# Compare Two Data Frame And Keep Columns That Match For Specific Row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames that have a row which are unique keys and are present in both data set. I want to keep only those columns in both where specific row value matches.

For below data `Data_1` has first row as `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, however `Data_2` only has `1`,`2`,`3`. I want compare or subset such that `Data_1` only has row first as `1`,`2`,`3`, as those keys are only present in both data frames.

Goal is not to merge, but to subset based on comparison of two different data frames.

Any suggestions on how to get this done?

**Data_1**

```
read.table(text = "A    B    C    D
       1    2    3    4
       1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
       1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
       1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
       1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
       1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4", header = T)
```

**Data_2**

```
read.table(text = "A1    B1    C1  
       1    2    3   
       1.0  2.2  4.3 
       1.0  2.2  4.3 
       1.0  2.2  4.3 
       1.0  2.2  4.3 
       1.0  2.2  4.3 ", header = T)
```

**Output**

Only `Data_1` changes as it has one extra row that isn't in `Data_2` based on row 2 values

```
read.table(text = "A    B    C
       1    2    3 
       1.1  1.2  1.3
       1.1  1.2  1.3
       1.1  1.2  1.3
       1.1  1.2  1.3
       1.1  1.2  1.3", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear. However, if you are simply trying to subset data_1 based on one row from data_2 the code below will work. In other words, the code below produces your desired "output" data frame.

```
data_1 <- read.table(text = "A    B    C    D
                             1    2    3    4
                             1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
                             1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
                             1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
                             1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
                             1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4", header = T)

data_2 <- read.table(text = "A1    B1    C1  
                             1    2    3   
                             1.0  2.2  4.3 
                             1.0  2.2  4.3 
                             1.0  2.2  4.3 
                             1.0  2.2  4.3 
                             1.0  2.2  4.3 ", header = T)

output <- data_1[data_1[1,] %in% data_2[1,]]

    A   B   C
1 1.0 2.0 3.0
2 1.1 1.2 1.3
3 1.1 1.2 1.3
4 1.1 1.2 1.3
5 1.1 1.2 1.3
6 1.1 1.2 1.3
```

Comment: .@glaucon - This is what I was looking for. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Just mark this as the correct answer (hit the check mark to go green)

Comment: .@glaucon - Done. Now I can't ask question again on `SO` for next 6 months, as `SO` says my questions are not received well. See you again in 6 months.

Comment: .@glaucon - Will your code work if I shuffle the column?

Comment: It depends if there is a match. For example, `data_1[data_1[2,] %in% data_2[2,]]` returns a blank data frame because there are no `TRUE` values in the test. In cases where there is a match, yes, the code will work.

Comment: .@glaucon - I think your code compares all the values in the column. What I am trying to achieve is to compare only specific row. For above data it's row 1 in both data sets that I want to compare and then subset accordingly.

Comment: try this `do.call(rbind, lapply(1, function(x) data_1[x, ][data_1[x, ] %in% data_2[x, ]]))` . Here is how this works. Each time you see "x", it will assume the value(s) stated immediately after `lapply`. This value corresponds to the row(s). So if you put in 1, you'll return a dataframe with the matches in row 1. If you put in 1:2, you'll return a dataframe with matches in rows 1 & 2. For your test data there is no matches in row 2 so the dataframe returned is only row 1. The `do.call` and `rbind` are both helpers to shape the `lapply` output. Hope this helps.

Comment: .@glaucon - Sorry, now this code in above comment is removing rest of the rows. Your code in above example is working correctly for the above test data, but not on my big data. It is definitely comparing all values in a row for my data, and not for the above test data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186323/discussion-between-glaucon-and-chetan-arvind-patil).